# NVDA is not reading correctly about the state change of accordion in Mozilla firefox. Is this a bug in Firefox?

Tags: accessibility, accordion, nvda

Below is the behavior by NVDA while reading in Firefox but reading correctly in Chrome

Firefox:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Comment: we need to see your code to help, could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thanks for your response. Here it is 

<input type="checkbox" class="ot-host-box" aria-expanded="true" role="button" ot-accordion="true" id="host-0" name="host-0" aria-label="First Party Cookies View Cookies" aria-controls="ot-host-acc-txt-0" tabindex="0">

Comment: hey, please could you make a fiddle of this, just seeing raw HTML within a comment makes it very difficult to help as we can't see how `aria-expanded` and checked states are handled. You can add a fiddle to your question (the icon with `<>` in it within the editor bar when you edit your question). You can edit your question using the `edit` in grey below the question tags. That will help see what libraries you are using etc.